# Replacing file name in XML by using Get-ChildItem command

Tags: xml, powershell-4.0

I am trying to use `Get-ChildItem` command to replace some file names in an XML. There are 6 file names in the XML and 6 files in each folder. All I want to do is replace the file names in the XML using the `Get-ChildItem` command
The file names always increment by 1 if that helps. So I have the following:

```psh
Get-ChildItem $dirname\resources\* -filter *.txt -recurse
```

Which gives back 6 file names. When I select an XML node, this also gives back 6 file names.

```psh
$xml.SelectNodes('//FileName',$XmlNSManager)
```

How do I synchronously replace each file name in the XML from the `Get-ChildItem` command? i.e

```
12341_1.txt --> 100011.txt,
12341_2.txt --> 100012.txt,
12341_3.txt --> 100013.txt,
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly something like this should work:

```psh
$files = Get-ChildItem $dirname\resources\* -Filter *.txt -Recurse |
         select -Expand Name | sort

$i = 0
$xml.SelectNodes('//FileName', $XmlNSManager) | % {
  $_.'#text' = [string]$files[$i]
  $i++
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error

    Cannot set "#text" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.
At line:6 char:3
+   $_.'#text' = $file[$i]
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XmlNodeSetShouldBeAString

Comment: Just going to try and explain a bit better.

$xml.SelectNodes('//FileName',$XmlNSManager) returns
#text                                                                                                                       
-----
8429006775491_01_01.txt
8429006775491_01_02.txt
8429006775491_01_03.txt
8429006775491_01_04.txt
8429006775491_01_05.txt
8429006775491_01_06.txt
I would like to replace those file names with the results of 
$files = Get-ChildItem $dirname\resources\* -Filter *.txt -Recurse |
         select -Expand Name | sort

Comment: @s4ndz See updated answer. An alternative would be defining the filename list as a string array (`[string[]]$files = Get-ChildItem ...`). No idea why the extra casting is required, because the array elements should already be strings.